# Converting a string to a mathematical function: "name sint is not defined"

Tags: python, string, function, sympy, symbols

I have a function `f(t,u,v)` in string format; for example `'t^2 * sint + u*(20 + t) + v*t'`.

How can I solve this function?

I tried to do:

```
t = Symbol('t')
u = mu
v = mv
sol = eval(f)
```

But I get error saying `name 'sint' is not defined`

Comment: i believe you're going to have to either write a custom parser, or convert things like `sint` to `math.sin(t)` before calling `eval()`

Comment: If you want `sint` to work, with no parentheses and not even any separator between `sin` and `t`, things are going to get ugly.

Comment: you'll also have to change `t^2` to `t**2`. it might be easiest to parse the strings, tokenize them, and convert them to python friendly tokens then use `eval()` to finish the program.

Comment: Use simple `eval('20^30'.replace('^', '**'))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `eval` is not the best approach.
[SymPy parser](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html) has options that allow for parsing strings with things like `t^2` (called `convert_xor`) and `sin t` (called `implicit_application`). Here is an example:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, standard_transformations, implicit_application, convert_xor
transformations = standard_transformations + (implicit_application, convert_xor)
f = parse_expr('t^2 * sin t + u*(20 + t) + v*t', transformations=transformations)
```

Now `f` is `t**2*sin(t) + t*v + u*(t + 20)` and you can work with it normally, for example

```
solve(f.subs({Symbol('u'): 4}), Symbol('v'))    # returns [-t*sin(t) - 4 - 80/t]
```

You may want to introduce `u, v, t = symbols('u v t')` to have easier access to those symbols.

Unfortunately `sint` will not be recognized as `sin(t)`; the lack of space is fatal. This will have to be preprocessed, probably with regular expressions. For example,

```
import re
s = re.sub(r'\bsin', 'sin ', 't^2 * sint + u*(20 + t) + v*t')
```

leaves a space after each "sin" (extra space will not hurt).

Answer (score 0):

This is rather ugly, but you could use regular expressions to (somewhat) format the expression before evaluating it. You'll probably have to hack around to adapt the below code to your needs.

```
import re
import textwrap
import math

functionBaseCode = textwrap.dedent("""
    def f({variables}):
        return {mathExpr}
    """)

def generateFunctionFromExpression(expression, variables):

    expression = expression.replace("^", "**")
    for fname in ["sin", "cos", "exp", "log", "sqrt"]:
         pattern = r"{fname} ?([a-zA-Z0-9]*)".format(fname = fname)
         replacement = r"math.{fname}(\1)".format(fname = fname)
         expression = re.sub(pattern, replacement, expression)

    variables = ", ".join(variables)
    mathExpr = expression
    funCode = functionBaseCode.format(
        variables = variables,
        mathExpr = mathExpr)

    # print(funCode)

    definitions = {}
    eval(compile(funCode, "<string>", "exec"), globals(), definitions)
    f = definitions["f"]

    return f

f = generateFunctionFromExpression("t^2 * sint + u*(20 + t) + v*t", "t u v".split())
g = generateFunctionFromExpression("x^2 + y^2", ["x", "y"])
# h = generateFunctionFromExpression("sqrt(x^2 + y^2)")
# l = generateFunctionFromExpression("log(sqrt(x)) - log(x) / 2", ["x"])
# h and l would fail because of the parenthesis after sqrt and log.

print(f(1, 1, 1)) # 22.8414
print(g(2, 3)) # 13
```